# TypeScript: declare a function with a required property on the function

Tags: typescript

Say I want a tagged function with an interface like:

```
interface TaggedFun {
    (args): void;
    tag: boolean;
}
```

It seems it's not actually possible to declare a function that match this signature (as any function literal will be missing the required `tag` property);

The only option is to make `tag` optional and remember to assign a value to it afterwards.

Is there any way to keep this type-safe (i.e. enfore the tag requirement in type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instances of `TaggedFun` in a factory function:

```
interface TaggedFun {
    (): void;
    tag: boolean;
}

function taggedFactory(tag: boolean, fn?: () => void): TaggedFun {
    let tagged = (fn || function () {
        // function body here
    }) as TaggedFun;

    tagged.tag = tag;
    return tagged;
}
```

This way you always know that you have the `tag` property (if you create the instance using the factory), and you get type safety.
For example:

```
function doSomething(tagged: TaggedFun) {}

doSomething(() => { }); // error 
doSomething(taggedFactory(true)); // ok
doSomething(taggedFactory(true, () => { })); // ok
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20TaggedFun%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tag%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20taggedFactory(tag%3A%20boolean%2C%20fn%3F%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20TaggedFun%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20tagged%20%3D%20(fn%20%7C%7C%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20function%20body%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%20as%20TaggedFun%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tagged.tag%20%3D%20tag%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20tagged%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doSomething(tagged%3A%20TaggedFun)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AdoSomething(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%20%0D%0AdoSomething(taggedFactory(true))%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0AdoSomething(taggedFactory(true%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D))%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok))

Answer (score 0):

Not in a clean way, the way to do it is as you said.

This is meant to support older style javascript where instead of classes you'd have functions with extra properties on them.

I would urge you to consider using a class instead.

Comment: This has to be a function and TypeScript doesn't seem to like extending Functions when targeting ES5. However, I am trying to see if I can do the work in the constructor....